# Local-global compatibility and modular curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, langlands-conjectures, modular-curves

I have been told by some people that local-global Langlands compatibility for $GL_2$ (the vanilla version, not the one being developed in this decade by Emerton and others) implies Shimura conjecture on reduction of the quotient of Jacobians of modular curves. How does this implication work? There are also some stronger results of Katz--Mazur, I think. Can Langlands be applied to prove them?

Comment: I believe the following notes by Daniel Litt address your main question: https://www.daniellitt.com/s/local-global.pdf

Comment: @JesseSilliman I am not sure they do so completely. The notes don't cite Katz--Mazur. Maybe the answer is easy to infer from that for someone experienced, not for me though.

Comment: What statements in Katz-Mazur are you interested in? It would be easier if you asked for the proof of a specific statement.

Comment: @WillSawin I am trying to make sense of a comment (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171831/are-there-any-simple-interesting-consequences-to-motivate-the-local-langlands-c#comment432295_171831), I am not quite sure about the exact theorem yet. Will try to figure it out.

Comment: I admit I was not sure what theorem you were interested in, but those notes describe how to use local-global compatibility to prove that the quotient $J_1(p)/J_0(p)$ has good reduction over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)^+$. I don't know if this is also what Katz-Mazur proves in its final chapter. These notes point out that it is not clear if the local-global proof is circular, as you need geometric input to prove local-global compatibility. I think Coleman gave another proof of this result by constructing a semistable model for $X_1(p)$ over this field.